# How to see the error and still keep the program on in the Python shell?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I know try/except can handle errors in my program.
But, is there a way of making **the error be displayed** in the program execution, be ignored and let the execution go on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBScript and other VB-derived languages, you can get this sort of behavior with "ON ERROR GOTO NEXT".

No such behavior exists in Python. Even if you wrap each top-level statement like:

```
try:
  do_something()
except Exception as e:
  print e

try:
  do_something_else()
except Exception as e:
  print e
```

you'd still have the result that statements within do_something are skipped at the point the exception is thrown.

Though perhaps if you have a particular use-case in mind, there may be other acceptable answers. For instance, in a top-level loop:

```
while True:
  cmd = get_command()
  if cmd == 'quit': break
  try:
    run_command(cmd)
  except Exception as e:
    print "Error running " + cmd + ":"
    print e
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import traceback

try:
    # do whatever you want
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Of course you should be more specific in a real scenario, i.e. you shouldn't catch and ignore all `Exception` instances, only the ones you are interested in and you know that they are safe to ignore.

Also note that if an exception happens somewhere within the `try..except` block, the execution will continue after the `try..except` block, not at the next statement. This is probably the closest to what you want to achieve.